# Ruby Class Diagram does not display in the Diagram menu of RubyMIne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have a Ruby on Rails project in RubyMine IDE so I want to generate the Class Diagram and when I click on 'Diagrams->Show Diagrams' teh IDE displays just:

- Rails Model Dependency Diagram
- Gem Dependency Diagram

I've checked the Ruby Class Diagram in the IDE Settings. Can someone help me to find out how to generate the Ruby Class Diagram with RubyMine please.!

[image]

Comment: Version 6.0.2 @zrl3dx

Comment: I'm missing that option too but in 5.x, in 6.x it works fine, try invalidating caches and restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've resolved that. I'm using both versions (6.0.2 and 5.4.3.2.1 - debugger issues) and in latter one I waas lacking that option. Go to `Settings > Diagrams`, uncheck everything and `apply`. You should be prompted about changes in `workspace.xml`. Accept that and you should have all three diagrams options available now.

If this won't help - invalidate caches, I'm not sure if it will delete `workspace.xml`. If not, delete `.idea` directory from your project and let RubyMine index it once again and recreate `workspace.xml`.

Comment: it works, but generates class diagram of all Ruby and not just the class diagram for my single project @zrl3dx

Comment: I see only my specific project classes, not whole Rails, did you check `default scope > project files`?

Comment: yes, I already check that and still generates the whole Rails Class Diagram @zrl3dx

Comment: Try changing that option and once again removing `.idea`, I've tried to get also Rails classes but i couldn't without it, it stalled, so maybe you've got same issue but in opposite way.